# How can I easily add a WPF Converter item template to Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, converters

I find myself **creating Converters** often and would like to be able to:

- right-click on my Converters folder
- Add New Item...
- choose Converter Item Template

I found [these instructions](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates) but I can imagine that there are **templates for standard files like WPF Converters** already available somewhere, does anyone know of any?

The following file would be created:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
class SaveStatusToSaveStatusMessageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the nerd+art snippets have a snippet called nerd_vc which generates a valueconverter for you. You can customize it to your liking, good luck!

http://www.blendables.com/files/folders/nerd_43_art/entry387.aspx

oh. sorry, i´m tired. what you want is not snippets.... I´ll leave the post here tough :)

Comment: actually I think a snippet is more convenient than a template, since it provides editable fields...

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but since it isn't what he asked for.. :)
note to threadstarter: snippets rule! :)